# vmap ops.index_update in Jax

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, jax

I have the following code below and it's using a simple for loop. I was just wondering if there was a way to vmap it? Here is the original code:

```
import numpy as np 
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.scipy.signal as jscp
from scipy import signal
import jax

data = np.random.rand(192,334)

a = [1,-1.086740193996892,0.649914553946275,-0.124948974636730]
b = [0.054778173164082,0.164334519492245,0.164334519492245,0.054778173164082]
impulse = signal.lfilter(b, a, [1] + [0]*99) 
impulse_20 = impulse[:20]
impulse_20 = jnp.asarray(impulse_20)

@jax.jit
def filter_jax(y):
    for ind in range(0, len(y)):
      y = jax.ops.index_update(y, jax.ops.index[:, ind], jscp.convolve(impulse_20, y[:,ind])[:-19])
    return y

jnpData = jnp.asarray(data)

%timeit filter_jax(jnpData).block_until_ready()
```

And here is my attempt at using vmap:

```
def paraUpdate(y, ind):
    return jax.ops.index_update(y, jax.ops.index[:, ind], jscp.convolve(impulse_20, y[:,ind])[:-19])

@jax.jit
def filter_jax2(y):
  ranger = range(0, len(y))
  return jax.vmap(paraUpdate, y)(ranger)
```

But I receive the following error:

> TypeError: vmap in_axes must be an int, None, or (nested) container
> with those types as leaves, but got
> Traced<ShapedArray(float32[192,334])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=0/1)>.

I'm a little confused since the range is of type int so I'm not too sure what's going on.

In the end, I'm trying to get this little piece optimized as best as possible to get the lowest time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`jax.vmap`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.html#jax.vmap) can express functionality in which a single operation is independently applied across multiple axes of an input. Your function is a bit different: you have a single operation iteratively applied to a single input.

Fortunately JAX provides [`lax.scan`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html) which can handle this situation. The implementation would look something like this:

```python
from jax import lax

def paraUpdate(y, ind):
    return jax.ops.index_update(y, jax.ops.index[:, ind], jscp.convolve(impulse_20, y[:,ind])[:-19]), ind

@jax.jit
def filter_jax2(y):
  ranger = jnp.arange(len(y))
  return lax.scan(paraUpdate, y, ranger)[0]

print(np.allclose(filter_jax(jnpData), filter_jax2(jnpData)))
# True

%timeit filter_jax(jnpData).block_until_ready()
# 10 loops, best of 3: 28.6 ms per loop

%timeit filter_jax2(jnpData).block_until_ready()
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 519 µs per loop
```

If you change your algorithm so that you'e applying the operation to *every* column in the array rather than the first *N* columns, it can be expressed with `vmap` like this:

```python
@jax.jit
def filter_jax3(y):
  f = lambda col: jscp.convolve(impulse_20, col)[:-19]
  return jax.vmap(f, in_axes=1, out_axes=1)(y)
```

Comment: That solves the issue I was having, thank you! I do have another problem though, I am noticing that the JAX equivalents no longer match the original pure python version of this code, what could be causing this?

```def filter_cpu(y):
  y[:,range(0, len(y))] = signal.convolve(impulse_20[np.newaxis, :], y[:,range(0, len(y))])[:, :-19]
  return y```

Comment: JAX defaults to 32-bit computations unless you set the X64 flag; scipy defaults to 64-bit computations. That might be the difference. Note also that jax has a 2D convolution available if you want to use that directly: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.scipy.signal.convolve2d.html